# LibreOffice System Font or Localization broken

Tags: libreoffice, fonts

In the menu and all user dialog of LibreOffice Writer the font is broken. Only the first letter of every word is correct, but the remaining part is cryptic:

[image]

Th language settings are correct, but I don't know how to set back the LibreOffice system font. The underlaying Ubuntu 16.04 works fine without displaying wrong fonts.

Comment: Can you also add (use "edit" to modify your question) what changes you did that could have caused the issue? Eventually try quiting LO, then renaming the hidden folder .config/libreoffice to .config/libreoffice_old. After that, a new factory default config will be created. If the issue persists after that, then you know the issue is not limited to your user settings.

Comment: After a reboot the problem disapeared. Thank for the advise on how to reset libreOffice to the factory defaults.